# Decomposition in cohomology from the antipodal map

Tags: differential-geometry

Consider the antipodal map $i:S^{n} \to S^{n}$, i.e $i:x\to −x$, its induces a decomposition $\Omega(S^{n})=\Omega^{n}_{+} (S^{n}) \oplus \Omega^{n}_{−}(S^{n})$, where $\Omega^{n}_{\pm}(Sn)$ consists of the differential forms satisfying $i^{*}\omega=\pm\omega$. I think its a simple question, but I don't understand why this yields a decomposition $H^{n}(S^{n})=H^{n}_{+}(S^{n})\oplus H^{n}_{−}(S^{n})$?

Comment: Becaus the differential in the complex restricts to the two summands.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because $i^*$ commutes with exterior derivative, so the complex $(\Omega , d)$ decompose into two complexes $(\Omega_\pm , d)$, then so are the cohomology groups